# Asynchronous Sockets Receive/Send doesn't receive/send the first byte

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a basic chat system for multiple people.
It sends messages and all, but except the first message sent from each client, each message's first byte is missing (whether the client didn't send it, or the server did not receive it).
Here is my client's Send and SendCallback:

```
private static void Send(Socket client, string data)
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        sendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

And here's my server's Accepter and ReceiveCallback:

```
private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    allDone.Set();

    Socket listenerSocket = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handlerSocket = listenerSocket.EndAccept(ar);
    if (!clientList.Contains(handlerSocket))
    {
        clientList.Add(handlerSocket);
    }
    // Creating the state object
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handlerSocket;
    handlerSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handlerSocket = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket.
    try
    {
        int read = handlerSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        if (read > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, read));
            handlerSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
                state);
        }


        if (state.sb.Length > 0)
        {
            string content = state.sb.ToString();
            foreach (Socket clientSocket in clientList)
            {
                Send(clientSocket, content);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            state.sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else
            handlerSocket.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I'll give an example of the problem:
client sends "hi",
server sees "hi" - everything is fine.
then:
client sends "hi"
server sees "i" - first character is missing.

What am I missing? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel with sockets?  You could use the `TcpClient` class which exposes a `Stream` via `GetStream()` which you can wrap with a `StreamReader` to read and write strings directly in a certain encoding (default is UTF-8).

Comment: Well... I wasn't aware of that option... But I still want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @TrevorElliott Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Where is the client receive code?